# How to handle Custom URLs on Tridion 2011 which are written in ASP on Tridion 2009?

Tags: 2011, 2009, custom-url

After our upgrade to Tridion 2011, I was trying to convert our Tridion 2009 Custom URL code written using ASP, to work on 2011. While working on this, I was stuck with a few API's that are not available on Tridion 2011.

On **Tridion 2009**, below is working as expected:-

```
window.dialogArguments.fieldValue
window.dialogArguments.fieldType
window.dialogArguments.isMultiValued
window.dialogArguments.publicationURI
```

On **Tridion 2011**, I changed the Custom URLs to use the below format but I didn't get back values from the Custom URLs as expected. For **firefox**, I get too few values back and on **IE** I get values as `undefined`.

### FireFox:

```
window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].properties.fieldDefinition.localName = SingleLineTextField
window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].isMultiValued = Undefined
window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].publicationURI = undefined
```

### IE:

```
window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].properties.fieldDefinition.localName = Undefined
window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].isMultiValued = Undefined
window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].publicationURI = Undefined
```

Please suggest how I might be able to fix this.

Comment: Hi Siva, if one of the answers below helped fix your issue, could you consider accepting it? (click the check mark next to that answer)

Comment: @BartKoopman: Thanks for the information :) . Actually I was working on it, thats the reason I haven't accepted. Once my testing is completed on it, I will accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Publication URI is available through the `controller` object which is available in the `window.dialogArguments`, so you should be able to use:

```
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItemPublicationUri()
```

Through the controller you can also get the actual item and related information, best to check it out in a debugger to see all available method.

`isMultivalued`is a method, so you should call it like: `window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].isMultivalued()`, that should return you the correct value.

It's unclear to me why `properties.fieldDefinition.localName` does not work in IE. I have the same behaviour while it works fine in Chrome and FF (something you should report to Customer Support). For the time being, perhaps you can try to use `window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].getTypeName()` instead, that does seem to return the fieldtype fine in both Chrome and IE for me.

Comment: When I was testing, `window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].isMultivalued()` is still not working and `window.dialogArguments.controller.getItemPublicationUri()` is working

Comment: window.dialogArguments.getFields()[0].isMultivalued() works fine for me on both Chrome and IE on 2011 SP1 HR1, so you might want to contact Customer Support if it doesn't for you.

Comment: I found `isMultivalued()` issue on FF. The problem is on 2009 `isMultiValued`, the letter `V` is Caps but on 2011 `isMultivalued()` letter `v` is small case.

Answer (score 5):

Another series of calls you might find helpful here and in the future are calls obtainable from `window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem()`.

**For example:**

```
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getSchemaId()
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getContent()
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getLockedById()
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getOwningPublicationId()
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getOrganizationItemId()
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getTitle()
window.dialogArguments.controller.getItem().getVersion()
```

.. and the list is quite large, check it out in Firefox Firebug Console command line.